# What is the environmental effect of personal protective equipment on the ocean?

Tags: oceanography, water, pollution

What is the environmental impact of masks and other personal protective equipment polluting the oceans?  The world is using billions of masks and gloves due to the COVID pandemic and they are being found amongst the trash in beach cleanups.

Comment: related question: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9003/how-much-garbage-goes-into-the-pacific-ocean-every-year